# less than validation not working after submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

i have a form with validation rule input3 value cant exceed input2 value, i have success before i submit the buttot, but when i submit the button i have a problem when i input a value on input3, anything input in input3 show message error.

input2 value depend on select list in left.

i use plug in fromvalidation for doing that.

this my form code

```js
$('#tambah').formValidation({
  icon: {
    valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
    invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
    validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
  },
  fields: {
    qty: {
      row: '.col-md-3',
      validators: {
        notEmpty: {
          message: 'Jumlah Barang Tidak Boleh Kosong'
        },
        lessThan: {
          value: $("#kolombayangan").val(),
          inclusive: true,
          message: 'Stok Tidak Tersedia'
        },
        integer: {
          message: 'Harus Berupa Angka'
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="tambah" id="tambah" role="form" action="aksi_tambahdetailpermintaan.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="kolombayangan" id="kolombayangan" >
  <div class="form-row">
    <input class="form-control" name="faktur" id="faktur" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $datapermintaan['no_suratjalan']; ?>">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-md-5">
        <select name="kodebarang" id="kodebarang" class="form-control">
          <option value=""></option>
          <?php $barang=m ysql_query( "SELECT tbarang.id_barang, tbarang.detail_barang, tpersediaan.saldo FROM tbarang 
       INNER JOIN tpersediaan ON tbarang.id_barang=tpersediaan.id_barang WHERE tpersediaan.saldo !='0' ORDER BY tbarang.id_barang ASC"); while ($databarang=m ysql_fetch_assoc($barang)) { ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $databarang['id_barang']?>">
            <?php echo $databarang[ 'detail_barang']?>
          </option>
          <?php } ?>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <input type="text" name="jumlah" id="jumlah" class="input-sm form-control" readonly>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group inputjumlah">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" class="input-sm form-control">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="text-right">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" id="tambah">Tambah</button>
    </div>
    <br>
  </div>
</form>
```

sorry for my bad english.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify a number for the `lessThan.value` property, but `.val()` returns a string.

To solve this, convert the return value of `val()` to number. This you can do with the [unary `+` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_%28%29):

```
    lessThan: {
      value: +$("#kolombayangan").val(),
      inclusive: true,
      message: 'Stok Tidak Tersedia'
    },
```

Secondly, you have two elements with the same `id` property value (*tambah*). This is not allowed in HTML. Some things might not work as expected unless this is corrected.

Comment: stil not working,lessthan value taken from first options selected. if options change and input2 change lessthan value stil old value.

Comment: In your HTML I did not find an element with id `kolombayangan`. Can you please provide it?

Comment: i was edit my question and add element with id kolombayangan.

Comment: But it has no value, so what do you expect the validation to do then? Your question is incomplete. There should be a clear example (visible in the code), and explanation of what you get with that example, and what was desired to happen.